# How to change the login and grub background image on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, grub

As the title explains I would like to change both of those background images but I was trying without success. What I've tried already:

#### GRUB

1. Added `GRUB_BACKGROUND="/home/jose/Imágenes/backgroundSea.png" to`
    `/etc/default/grub.`

```
root@kali:~# locate backgroundSea.png
/boot/grub/backgroundSea.png
/etc/grub.d/backup/boot_grub/backgroundSea.png
/home/jose/Imágenes/backgroundSea.png
```

> Output that shows that the path of the image is correct.

```
root@kali:~# update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-kali3-amd64
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-kali3-amd64
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-kali2-amd64
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

> Ouput of update-grub

```
root@kali:~# update-grub2
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/kali/theme.txt
using custom appearance settings
Found background image: /home/jose/Imágenes/backgroundSea.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-kali3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-kali3-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-kali3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-kali3-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-kali2-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-kali2-amd64
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

> Output of update-grub2

2. Adding the image to `/boot/grub`
3. Changing `/usr/share/desktop-base/kali-theme/grub/grub-16x9.png` with the image

#### LOGIN

Adding the file `login-background.png` to `/usr/share/desktop-base/`

#### GRUB Version

I'm not sure which version is using it seems like it has both installed.

```
root@kali:~# grub-install --version
grub-install (GNU GRUB 0.97)
```

```
root@kali:~# dpkg -l | grep grub | grep ii
ii  grub-common                               2.04-5kali1                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin                        2.04-5kali1                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 modules)
ii  grub-legacy                               0.97-75                              amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (Legacy version)
ii  grub2-splashimages                        1.0.1+nmu1                           all          a collection of great GRUB2 splashimages
```

```
root@kali:~# grub-probe -V
grub-probe (GRUB) 2.04-5kali1
```

Comment: Setting `GRUB_BACKGROUND=/path/to_image.png` and `sudo update-grub` should change the grub background image.

Comment: @Freddy already did that, except that i uninstalled sudo so I just use update-grub using su. However when the grub pops it has the default background.

Comment: `update-grub` should output something like 'Found background image:…' and you should find the image path in the generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (and replace the default image).

Comment: @Freddy added more information to clarify, also in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` there is this line `if background_image /home/jose/Imágenes/backgroundSea.png; then`, so I guess it should be working, even though it doesn't.

Comment: Please confirm your grub version. You appear to be using GRUB Legacy (`menu.lst`) and not GRUB2, that's totally different there.

Comment: @Freddy not sure which version it's using, depending on the command I use to display the version says legacy, grub2 or both are installed. The outputs are now in the post.

Comment: You can see the version on the grub boot screen. The `if background_image …` looks ok, but not `grub-install (GNU GRUB 0.97)`. I guess you need to install the `grub2-common` package which provides `grub-install` on my Debian, uninstall `grub-legacy` and reinstall with `grub-install /dev/sda` (if `/dev/sda` is your hdd). Then rerun `update-grub` and the output should be different.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem just tried running update-grub2 and gave a different output which made me think that grub2 is already installed, and also I realized that when the grub loads there is this little gap that you can choose the OS (in my case I only have Kali) and the background is the default one but **once** the OS is chosen then the background I've specified appears as background while it loads the login screen for 1 second or 2.

Answer (score 0):

About the login background, they have adopted `LightDM GTK+ Greeter` for support login screen. At least on my current version: `5.4.0-kali4-amd64`.

So, you just need to search for it in the menu, authenticate and change your background. Also, there's an option now for set a photo for login profile and a lot of other options.

And for the `grub` part, there's always the old and gold `grub-customizer`. Of course, as you can see it in [vitux](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-grub-customizer-on-ubuntu/), you'll need to add a repository, what could be the nightmare of a lot of Kali's users.

I know that I'm not exactly answering your question, giving another routes, but I think that someone could be interested in it. If someone wants the easy way:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

Answer (score 0):

Open *file system* as root. Go to /usr/share/grub/themes/kali and edit the two grub png files grub-16x9.png and grub-4x3.png (I renamed the originals to save them) Next do the same at /boot/grub/themes/kali I just replace these files with black pngs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).